# Derby included in Tomcat Webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, derby

My Web app connects to a Derby Database - OK.

My Web app and Derby are installed separately in my Tomcat 7 server - OK

Derby is installed using the **derby.war** file being deployed and by me moving the derby*.jar files into the Tomcat lib directory.

My Web app is deployed by exporting the war file into the Tomcat webapps directory.

I would like to deploy Derby without having to put the jars into the Tomcat `lib` directory - This could be a problem in production environments.

My question(s) is/are

Can the **derby.war** file be amended in anyway? - I tried adding a `WEB-INF/lib` directory and putting the derby*.jar files in there and re-deploying it. This didn't work, it actually removed the jars and the lib directory. Perhaps I need to do something else?

Or

Is there a way of including the derby jar files and the derby web.xml into my own web application? I tried this but not in anger, as my first attempt caused a few issues so I regressed back quickly in panic.

I will admit to you all now that my attempts to deploy Derby without using the Tomcat lib directory were a little rushed and I could have spent more time researching it. But I won't have access to that dev system for a while, I thought I'd ask if this could be/has been done by anyone.

Trevor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use tomcat datasource to connect to derby? I think if you use jdbc directly(initializing connection pool in the webapp using c3p0 or tomcat pools), it could be no problem to include derby jars in WEB-INF/lib. You can use embedded derby driver now. If you need derby network server, you could start it with a ContextListener, or you can configure the datasource in spring context if you are using spring.

Comment: Yes, I am using a data source to connect to Derby.

Comment: You need to use jdbc to embed derby in war. Just use c3p0 or tomcat pool to initiate the connection pool in war, using ContextListener is recommended.

Comment: As a side note... If I were to use the Derby embedded server instead of the network server, would this have a performance hit at all?

Comment: I think it is fine to use embedded server if the data is not that huge. If the database is big, you should use a seperate derby process(i.e. network server).

Comment: Thanks Sanigo, this is what I thought too.

Comment: BTW: If you are using spring, it is very simple to define the connection pool in spring context xml file.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer because I have managed to configure my web app to use the embedded server instead of the network server. An approach that I'd previously not considered but as it turns out, is probably much more suited to my needs than the network server anyway. 
Thanks for the help.